# Why is it possible to define two root paths in routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I want to route users on the public site (subdomain: www) to the landing page and users on a subdomain to their dashboard. So I experimented with different ways to do this and when I tried this:

```
root to: 'pages#landingpage', constraints: { subdomain: 'www' }
root to: 'dashboard#index'
```

Everything worked fine which is **not** what I expected. Since from what I understand `root to: 'examplecontroller#index'` expands to `get '/', to: 'examplecontroller#index', as: :root`, and defining two routes with the same name (`as` option) should raise an error.

Why does this not happen when using the `root` method, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. 
Usually the behavior I described is correct. That is, if you define a named route twice it raises an error:

```
      raise ArgumentError, "Invalid route name, already in use: '#{name}' \n" \
        "You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or " \
        "you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. " \
        "For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: \n" \
        "http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created"
```

However, there has apparently been some [discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10494) over whether this behavior should apply to root routes and a method was added to prevent multiple root declarations from [defining routes with the same name](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9704#issuecomment-18165452):

```
def match_root_route(options)
  name = has_named_route?(name_for_action(:root, nil)) ? nil : :root
  args = ["/", { as: name, via: :get }.merge!(options)]

  match(*args)
end
```